# Хорошая книга для изучения Pascal

Tags: pascal, книги

Здравствуйте! Поступил в этом году в очень сильный вуз где очень большое внимание уделяется программированию,но сам в программировании не селен(с трудом решаю С4 и то далеко не все). Подскажите хорошую книгу для более глубокого изучения Pascal.

Comment: прямо справа в связанных вопросах есть ответы [Книги по Free Pascal](http://hashcode.ru/questions/175828/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-free-pascal).

Но сколько того паскаля... алгоритмы нужно учить.

Comment: А есть какая-нибудь книга или по алгоритмам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из прочитанных больше всего мне понравилась Деревенец Олег - "Песни о Паскале" (вариант pdf в бесплатном доступе). Помимо самого языка включает довольно интересные задачи для решения и примеры алгоритмов. Только я не слышал, что бы сильные ВУЗы включали в свои программы обучения этот язык.

Есть очень много фундаментальных книг, которые желательно прочитать. Если составлять список, то он получится очень длинным. В том числе там и книги по алгоритмам.

1. Кормен - Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ.
2. Вирт - Алгоритмы и структуры данных
3. Кнут - Искусство программирования (для любителей хорошенько пораскинуть мозгами)

Можно тут посмотреть: [hashcode: литература-по-основам-программирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/283880/)

Answer (score 0):

[@0xFFh](/users/10774/0xffh) извините, я вас тут чем-то глубоко разобидел, что вы с таким раздражением читаете мне ваши эмоциональные отповеди относительно использования языков? Уж извините, но при всем уважении, не вам с высоты ваших 16 лет разглагольствовать относительно того, как и на что распределять время жизни тому или иному человеку (если конечно ваш возраст соответствует указанному)

Конкретно по сабжу - паскаль (помимо того, что им кто-то вроде по-прежнему пользуется для написания продакшн-кода) хорош именно как язык для обучения. Если вы полагаете, что обучение стоит начинать с С++, то это говорит лишь о вашем крайне поверхностном знакомстве с С++ - этот язык полон всяческих подводных граблей, запутанного и не очевидного для новичка синтаксиса, а одно из основных его правил - это сохранение совместимости с принципами программирования и кодом 40-летней давности. Сильно сомневаюсь, что тот же паскаль с его человекопонятным синтаксисомм (а для новичка это тоже немаловажно) будет худшим выбором.

Могу сказать по собственному (и много чьему еще) опыту, что начав в школе, а затем в институте с Паскаля я не имел ни малейших проблем в том, чтобы впоследствии, уже имея навыки программированя,  пересесть на другие, уже Си-подобные языки и затем забыть напрочь о существовании паскаля. Собственно, ваше гневное "да, пожалуйста, занимайтесь паскалем на здоровье" несколько не в тему - уже давно им не занимаюсь и знать его забыл, однако в определенной степени благодарен ему за первые шаги в программировании, за статическую типизацию, за человекопонятный синтаксис, за отсутствие корявых и неочевидных возможностей и подводных камней, что помогло в свое время сосредоточиться на изучении основ программирования и алгоритмизации, а не на борьбе с неочевидностями языка.

> А обучение программиста на базе Pascal, имхо, примерно то же самое, что обучение хирурга на примере медведя. Скиллы-то, конечно, появятся, но вот какой в них дальнейший смысл?

вы как-то ловко забываете, что речь вообще-то идет об изучении алгоритмов, структур данных и основ программирования, а не о паскале ради паскаля. Останутся как раз не скиллы кодинга на паскале, ценность которых не слишком высока, а навыки, связанные с алгоритмами, и не зависящие от конкретного языка.

Иными словами, не стоит вам так горячиться относительно этой старой развалины паскаля - от того, что миллионы программистов начинали именно с него, а потом пересели на что-то более подходящее, как можете заметить, небо пока не рухнуло на землю, а мир не погряз в пучине говнокода (а если и погряз, то виновен в этом явно не паскаль). Разумеется, есть ряд языков, которые были бы для старта не хуже (а может и чуть лучше) Паскаля, но он, смею вас заверить, в этом ряду далеко не худший даже сейчас

Answer (score 0):

Еще в школе за пару месяцев "изучил" паскаль по встроенной справке на английском без всяких учебников. Открывал описание функций, читал и придумывал задачи, где эти функции использовались бы. Этих двух месяцев хватило на 5 лет в ВУЗе.

Каким бы сильным ВУЗ не был - на паскале все равно не будут учить как строить приложения для космической промышленности. Поэтому, как таковых, углубленных знаний этого языка и не требуется.

А вот алгоритмы - это да. Их почти на любом языке можно реализовать. И че-то мне кажется, что цель ВУЗа - именно научить алгоритмам (на примере языка), а не самому языку.

Answer (score 0):

Паскаль изначально позиционировался автором как учебный язык. Базовые идеи его типизации каждый день пользуют и ООП, и СОЛИД, и проч. 
Однозначно:

Алгоритмы и структуры данных.

Потом, осознав записи, переходим к объектам, после них- к шаблонам. Если все сделать правильно, за несколько лет мозги расчешутся на правильный пробор.